# What is the practical use of compile time and load time weaving in AOP?

Tags: aop

What is the practical  use of compile time and load time weaving in Aspect oriented programming?

Comment: What is the meaning of life?

Answer (score 0):

If we have non functional code that scattered across the application then we will go for Aspect Oriented Programming.Best examples transactions in Spring AOP uses the compile time weaving.There are different types of weaving are possible in aspectj.

- Compile time  : Classes are weaved at the compile time. Means while compile the object itself join points are identified and advice is added over there. This is possible even implementing proxies. Spring AOP is completely proxy based.
- Load time  : While loading the object in to the memory weaved
- Runtime    : At run-time code is weaved.

Comment: If you can explain any practical scenario where each will be required .

Comment: Spring AOP is proxy based. Dynamic proxies or CGLIB proxies are done through the Runtime weaving. It is possible through the Loadtime weaving also.  Type of weaving depends on different factors involved. We can use AOP is Audit Log and Transaction.  For example LoadTime or Runtime weaving has execution overhead. This might impact response time for the first request.